# How are intercut scenes done?

Tags: screenwriting

I want to do a tennis scene done wit. A few separate rally scenes and some talking, where the two guys informally discuss a lawsuit in one or two of them... Do I need a new scene heading each time? I assume not, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, as far as I know, different scene heading are used when the setting changes. If the two discuss lawsuit between the game, maybe taking a break on the court side, I think one heading should fit. If the conversation happens elsewhere (the bar at the sport club, the showers, etc.) you have to make two scenes.

Disclaimer: I'm not a screenwriter, I just follow the examples I see written in scripts, so a professional should be able to give a better answer.

Comment: But how do I show time as having gone by like showing some shots while they’re playing and they’re talking then later in the match?

Comment: @Matt  use the score. Open the dialogue with a comment on the score. This should give the reader the impression that some time has passed and some more of the game has been played.

Comment: VERY nice! Ty sir

Comment: @Matt, as a general practice on Writing SE, it is advised that you mark an answer as accepted after few more answers come, so you give the chance to more people to express a better point of view. It's not a problem at all, it is just how I see it is done :)

Comment: Thank you for the advice and thank you for doing it in a constructive, friendly manner.

Comment: I think we all have experience with the alternative:)